# It's not printing because of few variables in Python

Tags: python, list, web, urllib2, concatenation

```
word1 = 'index.php/1'
word2 = 'index.php/2'
try:        
    tentativa1 = urllib2.urlopen(site + word1)
    tentativa2 = urllib2.urlopen(site + word2)

except URLError as e:
    tentativa1 = e
    tentativa2 = e

lista = [tentativa1, tentativa2]
    for website in lista:
     if website.code == 200:
        website = website.read()
        print '\n:)' if 'registration' in website else '\n:/'
        print '\n:)' if 'there is no form' in website else '\n:/'
```

I'm no getting error but isn't printing what should it. The idea is to input a website concatening with two or more strings, then the ".read()" if find the "keywords" would print ":)".

Comment: Maybe you must do `website = website.read().lower()?`

Comment: I don't know what is ".lower()" sorry, but I put as you said and still not priting

Comment: you have not correct tab in line `for website ...` and `if website ...`

Comment: Can you say what the code is supposed to do? Have you verified that control passes to the line that says `lista = [tentativa1, tentativa2]`? Why do you redefine tentativa1 and tentativa2 only when you get exceptions?

Comment: sheh: Tab line it's wrong in stackoverflow xD, in my notepad it's correct

Comment: duhaime: Is supposed to check some "keywords" in a website, if that "keyword" is found then would print ":)". But it's not printing. I don't get your second question. I redefined because if tentativa1 or tentativa2 get some URLerror, I would print the error status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code and say me what print output

```
sites = [site + 'index.php/1', site + 'index.php/2']

for url in sites:
    try:
        website = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except URLError as e:
        print '{}: {}'.format(url, repr(e))
    else:
        if website.code == 200:
            website = website.read().lower()
            print '\n:)' if 'registration' in website else '\n:/'
            print '\n:)' if 'there is no form' in website else '\n:/'        
        else:
            print '{}: code {}'.format(url, website.code)
```

Comment: Now has printed but printed the four "print" ones ":/ :) :/ :)". Looks like that hasn't verified if the strings exist in the source code.

Comment: this output mean what website contains only `there is no form`, not `registration`